# How to translate Вырвиглазный into English?

Tags: перевод, прилагательные

Can you, please, help me translate the adjective `вырвиглазный` into English?

Usage: `вырвиглазный баннер`, `вырвиглазный перевод`. Synonyms:

- `аляповатый`
- `дебильный`
- `запредельный`
- `мозговыносящий`
- `мозговырывающий`
- `мозгоразрывающий`
- `стрёмный`
- `ужасный`

Comment: The original meaning of "вырви-глаз" is "very acidic" (relates to taste of food products).

Comment: Something like "eye-rending", perhaps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about "**eye-popping**"? Not exactly the same meaning, but it has the right visual.

Alternatively you could call those banners **ugly**, **unsightly** or **hideous**. **Fugly**, if you choose to be explicit.

Translations can be **abhorring**, **baffling** or **unfathomable**.

So that's the shortlist! I used a http://www.thesaurus.com for this answer. I'm sure you can find something that speaks to your particular case there. Good luck!

Comment: Please, add a link to the thesaurus.

Answer (score 4):

Urban Dictionary has some variants:

> [**eye-hurt**](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Eye-hurt) - A visible object that hurts your brain when viewed. This could be an ugly-ass girl/guy, or a crappy piece of art.
>
> *Damn website font is eye-hurt!*

.

> [**eyesore**](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=eyesore) - Ugly, hard on the eyes.
>
> *Since you painted your house electric pink it has become the eyesore of the neighborhood.*

.

> [**eye trash**](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=eye%20trash) - anything that is a visually offensive; i.e. a waste of good scenery; worse than an **eye sore**.
>
> *All the "cookie cutter" urban sprawl is eye trash for nature.*

Comment: Alas, none of those is an adjective...

Comment: @VictorBazarov - Come on! English nouns can be used as attributes.

Comment: Try it.  "This is such an eye-sore banner".  "This is such an eye-hurt banner". "I saw an awful eye trash translation".

Answer (score 1):

I'd add "gaudy" to a list of possible translations.
According to the google dictionary it means: extravagantly bright or showy, typically so as to be tasteless. Seems to be pretty close to `вырвиглазный` in my impression.

Comment: I think the most important trait of "вырвиглазный" is to refer to the pain the beholder endures when watching the item.  "Gaudy" has no such connotation (at least to me).